# SELECT Ambiguous/Invalid Column runtime error

Tags: abap, opensql

When I run my ABAP Program, I get a runtime error `DBIF_DSQL2_SQL_ERROR` at the `SELECT...` line with this error text:

> invalid column error and ambiguous column error for VBAK and VBAP tables and the VBELN column

ABAP code:

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Report  ZSAM
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

REPORT  ZSAM.

DATA: BEGIN OF wa,
      vbeln TYPE VBAK-VBELN,
      vtweg TYPE VBAK-VTWEG,
      posnr TYPE VBAP-POSNR,
      matnr TYPE VBAP-MATNR,
      vrkme TYPE VBAP-VRKME,
      END OF wa.

WRITE: 'vbeln', 'vtweg', 'posnr', 'matnrr','vrkme'.


EXEC SQL PERFORMING loop_output.
   SELECT VBAK-VBELN, VBAK-VTWEG, VBAP-POSNR, VBAP-MATNR, VBAP-VRKME
   INTO :wa
   FROM VBAK INNER JOIN VBAP on VBAK-VBELN = VBAP-VBELN
ENDEXEC.

FORM loop_output.
   WRITE: / wa-vbeln, wa-vtweg, wa-posnr, wa-matnr, wa-vrkme.
ENDFORM.
```

What might be the problem in the code and how to resolve it?

Comment: Any special reason for using native SQL?

Comment: Just training. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Of course there is and it is called Open SQL. One can understand it as a special version of SQL for ABAP. You should in fact use only Open SQL as then you are making your code RDMS Independent. Using native SQL often ties you to a native database management system, even if you try using the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use . instead of - as separator. You are writing native SQL, so you must apply db specific rules.

```
EXEC SQL PERFORMING loop_output.
   SELECT VBAK.VBELN, VBAK.VTWEG, VBAP.POSNR, VBAP.MATNR, VBAP.VRKME
   INTO :wa
   FROM VBAK INNER JOIN VBAP on VBAK.VBELN = VBAP.VBELN
ENDEXEC.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use native SQL for such a simple query. As you wrote that you are actually learning ABAP at the time, then switch immediately to Open SQL.

```
SELECT vbak~vbeln, vbak~vtweg, vbap~posnr, vbap~matnr, vbap~vrkme
  INTO @DATA(l_work_area)
  FROM vbak INNER JOIN vbap ON vbak~vbeln = vbap~vbeln.
  WRITE: / l_work_area-vbeln, l_work_area-vtweg, l_work_area-posnr, l_work_area-matnr, l_work_area-vrkme.
ENDSELECT.
```